# Change notebook kernel in the background

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am trying to change the kernel of the notebook by changing the metadata of the notebook ie I have a service that will parse the notebook JSON and change the kernelspec in the metadata of the notebook JSON. But on the jupyterlab UI, it still shows the old kernel instead of the kernel in the notebook metadata. Do I need to make any changes elsewhere?

Any help or tips are appreciated.